# inverse elements in quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/_{\langle 560 \rangle}$

Tags: inverse, quotient-group

im currently study for exam and I have a problem that I forgot how to solve. I have the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/_{\langle 560 \rangle}$.

How do I find how many inverse elementes exists in the ring? and how do I find the inverse of $99+\langle 560 \rangle$?

thank you.

Comment: @Surb He may be talking about the monoid $\mathbb Z/\left<560\right>$ and mistakenly called it a group. In which case the invertible elements are those that aren't zero divisors.

Comment: Finding multiplicative inverses in modular arithmetic is a standard application of Bézout's identity, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: actually I meant ring, not group. I feel like I need to use GCD somehow, but don't know how and where to start. And I will try using Bézout's identity, thank you

Comment: $n$ is invertible (for multiplication) iff $\gcd(n,560)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended Euclidean algorithm:

$$560=5×99+65\\99=1×65+34\\65=1×34+31\\34=1×31+3\\31=3×10+1$$.

So $(99,560)=1.$

Now work backwards: $$1=31-\color{red}{3}×10=31-(\color{red}{34-1×31})×10=11×\color{purple}{31}-10×34=11(\color {purple}{65-1×34})-(10)34=11×65-(21)×\color {orange}{34}=11×65-
(21)(\color {orange}{99-1×65})=32×\color {blue}{65}-21×99=(32)(\color{blue}{560-5×99})-21×99=32×560-181×99.$$

So $99^{-1}\equiv-181\equiv379\pmod{560}.$